# Whats wrong with my MySQL PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting error:
[24-Nov-2013 02:13:58] PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home5/mwtwoone/public_html/sw6/ebay/test.php on line 17

The error is referring to the line mysql_query($con,"UPDATE codes SET multi = '1' WHERE `code` == $code_array[0]");

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect(Localhost,"mwtwoone_xbl","223822","mwtwoone_xbl");
mysql_select_db( 'mwtwoone_xbl' );


$sqlcodes = "SELECT `code` FROM `codes` WHERE `sent` = 0";
$rawcodes = mysql_query($sqlcodes); // process the query

$code_array = array(); // start an array

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rawcodes)){ // cycle through each record returned
$code_array[] = $row['code'];
}


echo $code_array[0]; // output the string to the display
mysql_query($con,"UPDATE codes SET multi = '1' WHERE `code` == $code_array[0]");
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I've been messing with this for all now and cant seem to fix it, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Why do you think `$con` as the first argument to `mysql_query` is correct?

Comment: same type of question coming from different users is it a part of spamming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172751/php-and-mysql-query-what-am-i-doing-wrong-here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using, use `=` instead of `==` and `$con` should be `mysql_query($query, $con)`

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE codes SET multi = '1' WHERE `code` ='".$code_array[0]."' ");
```

instead of

```
 mysql_query($con,"UPDATE codes SET multi = '1' WHERE `code` == $code_array[0]");
```

Syntax: **resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )**

Comment: Still got the same error! Ahh

Comment: Worked! Wow thanks so much I cant believe you did that so fast after all my troubles.

Comment: NP, glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am correct. in this structure you don't need 2 equal signs "== " just one is enough. give it a try .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use mySQLi or PDO, mySQL is deprecated.

This should work.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 'value1' WHERE `column2` ='".$array[0]."' ");
```